# How to populate html table with array of objects each time it's added

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop, html-table

I have this array of objects
[image]

I want to populate an Html table with this data anytime it is added.
[image]

Looking like this
[image]

I have tried using this function

```
function addDataToTbody(table, data) { // table -> NodeList, data -> array with objects
    data.forEach((d, i) => {
        var tr = table.insertRow(i);

        Object.keys(d).forEach((k, j) => { // Keys from object represent th.innerHTML
            var cell = tr.insertCell(j);
            cell.innerHTML = d[k]; // Assign object values to cells   
        });

        table.appendChild(tr);
    })
}
```

But it keeps returning all the objects in the array each time the add button is clicked
[image]

Please help with this.

Comment: Is the data variable cleared between events, it looks like you're simply pushing the clicked item into the same array and calling your function with that. So either clear the data array once the items are added, or clear the table before processing the data (less recommended)

Comment: @Milton I can do that but if i update the quantity input value and add new item (also clearing the data array), it clears everything including the quantity.